# How to position a View at an specific point on a background layer, regardless of screen dimentions?

Tags: android, layout, view, position, overlay

I want to place a collection of views at predefined locations on an image background.

Like this:
[image]

I can set the position each Coffee cup View in XML, using the top/Left margin or android:TranslationX/android:TranslationY.

When the app starts on a screen with different dimensions, my background layer will stretch to the new layout, but **how can I alter the Top/Left Margins of my Views?**

Ideally, I would just mark up, in XML, the position of each view as x% from the left and y% from the top of the parent. (Animations can work a bit like this). That option does not appear to be available.

Some explorations I've considered:

- **Use Layout weighting.** This would solve the problem if I was only interested in the vertical or horizontal position, but I can't see how to do both at the same time.
- **Design for a specific, reference screen size, using margins to position the cups, then scale the top/left margins of the Views at runtime.** This involves reading the starting margin at runtime and resetting it to a proportion of the reference screen. If my reference screen is 1000px wide and I'm running on 750px wide screen, I could read the layoutParams, multiply the left margin by (750/1000) and write the resulting left margin back to the layout. But getLayoutParams does not give me an object that has margins.
- The closest I've come to getting this working has been with **setting android:translationX and android:translationY.** In principle it should be a simple matter of setting these values to work on a reference screen in the XML (say a 10.1" tablet) and scaling these to the actual device in use. I couldn't get sensible results this way. By trial-and-error I found that with raw values set in the XML for a Galaxy 10.1" tab, and running on a Galaxy nexus (in landscape), I had to *add* 900 to the values from getTranslationX/Y() so the resulting icons appeared correctly. But 900 is just an arbitrary number and, of course adding them screwed up the positions on the 10.1" tab, so it's not a solution.

Either an XML or programmatic solution would be fine.

Comment: Is the image in the background an ImagwView?

Comment: No. It's set with android:background="@drawable/..." at my top-level XML file.

Comment: Can you get the ratio of on-screen pixels to image pixels with getWidth()/getBackground().getIntrinsicWidth(), and then multiply that by the pixel position on the original image?

Answer (score 0):

Using Relative layout, you can relatively place your icons where you want them to be.

You can create a transparent image, slice them into where the map corresponds, and then use relative layout to put them there.

This might be a stupid solution...
But it worked for me.

Since I can't put images, I'll try to explain them with characters. (Sorry!!!)

----------------------------------------a

```
            I
```

--------------------I-------------------a

```
       I            I
```

-------------I--------------------I-----a

Like that and so on.. (Ignore the 'a's)
Each box represents a slice of the transparent image.
You place your icons on the 'I's or wherever you want

(Sorry again!!!)